# Problem with 3D printing my blender mesh [Inverted Print]

Tags: 3d-printing

So, I have a mesh that I've made in blender 2.8.
When I went to print it / send it to the slicing software, it showed up completely inverted. Inverted as in all the hollow spaces printed but nothing else. The following is the blender image (what it's supposed to look like) vs the slicer img (the inverted mesh). If anyone knows what this is happening / inverted it would be extremely helpful. This is for my school project which is due next week so I'm very rushed on time. Thank you!

(PS. I've checked all the problems that generally occur, even the ones that seemed unrelated but it still doesn't work. Normals are correct, it's a singular object, all modifiers have been applied, etc.)
[image: This is the blender file, I attempted to show most angles]

[image: This is what it looks like in the slicing software]

This is the selected Non-Manifold faces
[image: Selected Non-Manifold]

I've fixed this now, (also there were no interior faces) and I reloaded a fresh STL export into the slicer, and it still happens. Any ideas?
[image: Fixed Manifold]

Comment: Please make sure your object is Manifold : In edit mode, unselect all, then Select menu / Select by Trait / Non manifold ;  if some faces are selected, they're problematic (please edit your question and show a screenshot of those faces). Do the same with "Interior Faces".

Comment: Alright, I changed a few things and it worked. I think the biggest issue was the non-manifold stuff, so thanks :).

Comment: One possible thing to check in this case is if object scale is negative. It can be done by applying it and *then* checking normals orientation (in 2.8 inverted faces in default shading won't be grey so you have to make sure to check that)